# Failed to post large data (>9MB) using libCurl

Tags: libcurl

I am getting failure while sending large data (neraly 9-10 MB) using C++ Libcurl, where as the data of lesser size works fine. 
i am trying to send the data from linux machine to Exchange Server (windows 2008). from wireshark capture, i could see initial few packets are getting uploaded successfully, but then i could see errors like TCP retransmissions, TCP Zero size Window, TCP Window update etc. Apart from these packets i could see one packet related to HTTTP 400 , followed by TCP RST (thereby terminating the connection).

source Address (linux machine ): 10.65.156.77 
Destination ipaddress (exchange server) = 10.76.214.38
libcurl version : 7.30

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So, sounds like the servers responds with a 400 and then libcurl stops sending, or trying to send, any data

Comment: yes, i have wireshark traces with me but i am not able to post them. is there any other way by which i can share the same